# Run a code without being on the physical machine

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-3b+, server

I have some devices (i.e. leds) that I need to control on a Raspberry Pi, but I was thinking if there is a way in which I can put the code in a server, and then when the raspberry Pi receives a certain command to turn on a led, it takes the command from the server. I need to achieve this thing as I dont need to show the code to the client on the raspberry pi. I am using .net core. This is for educational purpose not for business.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My pigpio library lets you control the GPIO of one or more Pis from another machine on the network.  The other machine may be a Windows, Linux, Mac, or Android machine.  It's simplest if the other machine can run Python.

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html

An easier approach might be to use the [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) software.  [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is supported by the Raspberry Pi foundation and uses the services of pigpio to handle the GPIO.

I am not familiar with .NET.

Have a look at this [.NET](https://github.com/unosquare/pigpio-dotnet) interface to pigpio provided by unosquare.

Comment: This is what I need, but my application is running on .net core. Is there an equivalent library?

Comment: @TheCondorIV  I have no idea what .net core is.  If it is relevant you should edit that information into your question.